# É possível atribuir o valor padrão de uma propriedade com um atributo?

Tags: c#, .net, reflexão

Eu gostaria de poder declarar uma propriedade como:

```
[DefaultValue(10)]
public int Maximo { get; set; }
```

E quando fosse utilizar ela, já viesse com o valor iniciado em `10`. Entretanto o atributo não atribui o valor, quando tento usar:

```
public void FazAlgo()
{
    int max = Maximo; // 0
}
```

O valor vem `0`, que é o padrão do inteiro.

Uma alternativa seria criar um campo e implementar o `get` e `set`, mas estou buscando um modo de fazer isto sem a necessidade de implementar os métodos.

Gostaria de fazer com atributos da forma que exemplifiquei, é possível? Como?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O [atributo `DefaultValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), como dito na especificação, por si só não altera o valor da propriedade. Ele serve para ser utilizado pelo editor de design e geradores de código.

É possível utilizar *[Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/f7ykdhsy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)* (note que *reflection* tem/(pode ter) um custo de performance, não é recomendado para substituir atribuições triviais) para iniciar as propriedades, o seguinte método de extensão obtêm todos as propriedades da classe e verifica pelo atributo `DefaultValue`, caso encontre ele obtêm o valor do atributo e atribui a propriedade.

```
public static class Extensoes
{
    // método de extensão para `Object`, funcionando assim em
    // todas classes
    public static void InicializaValores(this Object o)
    {
        // obtem todas propriedades, campos...
        var propriedades = o.GetType()
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static);

        // para cada propriedade
        foreach (var propriedade in propriedades)
        {
            // pega o atributo DefaultValue
            var atributos = propriedade
                .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DefaultValueAttribute), true)
                .OfType<DefaultValueAttribute>().ToArray();

            // se encontrou
            if (atributos != null && atributos.Length > 0)
            {
                // pega o atributo
                var atributoValorPadrao = atributos[0];

                // seta o valor da propriedade do objeto o
                // para o valor do atributo
                propriedade.SetValue(o, atributoValorPadrao.Value, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Com este método para ler o valor dos atributos e associar com a propriedade, ainda é necessário invocar o método.

Isto pode ser feito no construtor da classe, por exemplo:

```
public class Teste
{
    [DefaultValue(10)]
    public int Maximo { get; set; }

    public int Minimo { get; set; }

    public Teste()
    {
        this.InicializaValores();
    }
}
```

Testando:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new Teste();

        // poderia ser feito aqui também
        //test.InicializaValores();

        Console.WriteLine(test.Maximo); // 10
        Console.WriteLine(test.Minimo); // 0

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Por curiosidade: quando isto é útil? Em termos gerais isso substitui um trabalho simples que seria feito no construtor por um bem mais complexo e com pior performance. A única vantagem que vejo em um primeiro momento é que o valor default fica junto a propriedade, mas só por isso não valeria a pena.

Comment: Sim, _reflection_ tem seu custo. Como disse no topo, isso pode ser usado para _design editors_, ao invés de chamar no construtor chamaria o método que iria iniciar os valores do controle para colocá-lo na tela.

Answer (score 3):

```
public int Maximo { get; set; } = 10 
// Somente na versão do .NET mais nova, não sei qual exatamente
```

ou, feio mas simplista:

```
public bool _maximoFoiAlterado;
public int _maximo;
public int Maximo 
{ 
get
{
    if (!_maximoFoiAlterado) return 10;
    else return _maximo;
}
set
{
    _maximoFoiAlterado = true;
    _maximo = value;
}
}
```

Comment: Desde a versão 9: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties